# Displaying errors from backend to frontend in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, error-handling

Good day/evening,

i want to display the error messages to my client. I am console logging the error status code, but it doesn't console log the message. What am i missing ? I am using React as my frontend.  Thank you in advance for answering

code Route:

```
//create route for register
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    //check if fields are empty
    const { name, email, password, rePassword } = req.body;
    if (!name || !email || !password || !rePassword) {
        console.error("Fields are empty");
        res.status(401).send("fields are empty");
    }

    //passsword length should be at leats 6 characters
    if (password.length < 6) {
        console.error("Passwords should at least be 6 characters");
        return res
            .status(401)
            .send("Password should at least be 6 characters long");
    }
    //checking if passwords match
    if (password !== rePassword) {
        console.error("Passwords do not match!");
        return res.status(401).send("Passwords dont match");
    }
    //check if user exists
    const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (emailExist) {
        console.error("User already exists");
        return res.status(409).send("User already exists");
    } else {
        //create salt
        const salt = await genSalt(10);
        //hashing the password
        const hashedPassword = await hash(req.body.password, salt);
        const user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword,
            isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
        });
        const newUser = await user.save();
        res.send(newUser);
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});
```

code Frontend fetching:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        fetch("http://localhost:5000/users/register", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name,
                email,
                password,
                rePassword,
            }),
        })
            .then(response => {
                localStorage.setItem("TOKEN", response.formData.token);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                }
            });
    };
```

Comment: Hi, the success response is the promise object you need to await it get the `formData.token`
see the exmaple https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: response => { ... response.json().then(result => { result.message} ) }

Comment: @emsiiggy could you be more clear?

Comment: Just like you did .then after fetch, you need to do it on response. But firstly i'd convert it to json, so use response.json().then( data => {console.log(data)} )

Comment: @emsiiggy i am getting this error when i try to json the response: index.js:1 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1

Comment: maybe try response.text() instead of response.json(). @Reactord

Comment: I'll advice you using `axios` because in the `fetch API` success and error are handles in the `then` or `try block(if using try...catch)`.With axios you can `catch` the error in the right place by `error.response.data`